# Illegal string offset and Uninitialized string

Tags: php

I've written the code below, but I don't understand why I get these errors.

What I basically want to achieve is that this code checks if the forms are filled, and if not, it outputs an error. The strange thing is that it works on the first one, with (`$name['name']`), but after that, it won't work..

```
    <?php 
    $name = "";
    $username = "";
    $password = ""; 

    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];

    if(isset ($name['name']) || ($username['username']) || ($password['password'])) {
        echo "Hurray, user was created!";
    } else {
        echo "Looks like something isn't filled out, try again!";
    }
?>
```

Comment: You already dereferenced the input array with `$_POST["name"]`, so the `$name` var etc. will already contain a string. No need to add an array index in the `if` therefore.

Answer (score 0):

Something like the following may work for you...

```
    if(isset($_POST['name']) && isset($_POST['username']) && isset($_POST['password'])) {
        echo "Hurray, user was created!";
    } else {
        echo "Looks like something isn't filled out, try again!";
    }
?>
```